# Android: How to wait IntentService for BroadcastReceiver onReceive method

Tags: android, wait, intentservice, notify, android-broadcastreceiver

I have IntentService that need to wait in method a() for results of onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver().

For now i use lmao wait(5000)... so it's not too elegant

**IntentService:**

```
private boolean methodA() {

try {
            synchronized (mLocalBroadcastReceiver) {
                mLocalBroadcastReceiver.wait(3000); 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"error, thread interrupted");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

if(CONSTANT == true){ 
   return true;
else 
   return false;
}
```

**BroadCastRecievier:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    CONSTANT = true //changes somehow between true/false 
}
```

In other words: return value of methodA depends on results of onReceive(). How to synchronize two threads?

Comment: call methodA() inside of onReceive method

Comment: start by reading the documentation for IntentService, because this is not what it is for

Comment: @TimCastelijns my IntentService do more others offload tasks, not just methodA(), methodA() is small part

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used thread like that:

```
 private void waitForResponse() {
        //wait for response
        thread = new WaitForStatus();
        thread.run();
        try {
            synchronized (thread) {
                thread.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class WaitForAppStatus implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (CONSTANT  != -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            wait(400);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```